# os.path.exists() will create that file

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I am using the following codes to write some log into a new file, every time I run the program. But it seems like that os.path.exists() is creating all the files every time I run it. I am using a mac with OS X 10.10.3.

```
for idx in range(0, 100):
    if os.path.exists(str(idx) + ".out.txt"):
        continue
    else:
        output_file = open(str(idx) + ".out.txt", "w")
```

If I run the python script in terminal, i.e., "python ./that_code.py" or in IDE, `.exists()` will create the files. But simply running `.exists()` in IPython will not create the file.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake, there is supposed to be a `break` after the `output_file = ...` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're completely correct that

```
for idx in range(0, 100):
    if os.path.exists(str(idx) + ".out.txt"):
        continue
    else:
        output_file = open(str(idx) + ".out.txt", "w")
```

...creates all the files in question. You're **entirely wrong** that it's the `os.path.exists()` line doing it.

```
        output_file = open(str(idx) + ".out.txt", "w")
```

...creates the files it opens for write. Replace that line with `pass`, or just delete the `else` clause entirely, and you'll see that creation no longer takes place.

---

Incidentally -- in Go, this pattern would be considered bad practice, and someone wanting to ensure that these hundred files exist would be advised to open them for write unconditionally, without checking whether they existed previously. This approach avoids race conditions -- what happens if the file's existence changes between the `os.path.exists()` call and the `open()` -- and also reduces `stat()` calls.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create the file if it doesn't exist, but NOT clobber it if it does. In that case, you might want to (unconditionally, as Mr. Duffy suggests) open the file for append (`"a"`) rather than for write (`"w"`).

Comment: @Edward couldn't you just unconditionally open it for append, then?

Comment: The fix is probably to add a `break` after the `output_file = ...` line.

Comment: @EthanFurman, that depends on what the OP actually wants to do. Maybe they want to precreate all hundred files to avoid any chance of running out of inodes later. If they're not going to tell us their intent, why second-guess? :)

Comment: Forcing people to clarify their question before they get a good answer means maybe they'll think to write a better question in the future.